# Getting Could not resolve proxy: --global when publishing new branch

Tags: git, proxy, bitbucket

I am able to run `git pull` to fetch the latest changes from corporate bitbucket server. But when I tried to publish a newly created local branch it is throwing **Could not resolve proxy: --global**

Note that I was able to publish the new local branches without any issue in the past. I tried un-setting the proxy (local, global and system) but nothing helped.

Answer (score 0):

After trying all the step mentioned to unset the proxy I am able to fix it using `--force` flag.

Run `git push -u origin urLocalBranchName --force`